# Tie children of one div to children of another div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two parent divs: `.inputs` and `.infoBoxes`. Each of them have an equal number of children. When the user clicks into the first `.input` in `.inputs`, the first `.infoBox` in `.infoBoxes` should `slideDown()`. Same for second, third, etc. I'd like to do this without re-writing the same code for each pair. So far I have:

```
var $inputs = $('.inputs').children();
var $infoBoxes = $('.infoBoxes').children(); 

for(var i = 0; i < $inputs.length; i++ ) {
    $($inputs[i]).find('.input').focus(function() {
        $($infoBoxes[i]).slideDown();
    })
    $($inputs[i]).find('.input').blur(function() {
        $($infoBoxes[i]).slideUp();
    })
}
```

This isn't working but I have tried replacing `i` with the indexes of each div.

```
$($inputs[0]).find('.input').focus(function() {
    $($infoBoxes[0]).slideDown();
})
$($inputs[0]).find('.input').blur(function() {
    $($infoBoxes[0]).slideUp();
})
repeat...
repeat...
repeat...
```

This works but isn't very DRY. I'm looking for a better solution that won't have me repeating a bunch of code.

Comment: Provide your HTML as well, so that we know the structure.

Comment: Use bind or add onfocus in html itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First code will not work, because you using same variable for all internal functions. You should wrap it into function, which will create local variable for index. Try following code:

```
var $inputs = $('.inputs').children();
var $infoBoxes = $('.infoBoxes').children(); 

for(var i = 0; i < $inputs.length; i++ ) {
    (function(ix) {
      $($inputs[ix]).find('.input').focus(function() {
        $($infoBoxes[ix]).slideDown();
      })
      $($inputs[ix]).find('.input').blur(function() {
        $($infoBoxes[ix]).slideUp();
      })
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`slideDown`](https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) is used for showing elements. I am guessing you want to hide elements, since you are clicking on them and you cant click an hidden element. Use [`hide`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) or [`slideUp`](https://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) to hide elements.

```js
$(".input, .infobox").on("click", function() {
  var ind = $(this).index();
  $(".infobox:eq(" + ind + "), .input:eq(" + ind + ")").hide(500);
});
```

```css
.input,
.infobox {
  widht: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0;
  color: white;
}
.input {
  background: red;
}
.infobox {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputs">
  <div class="input">1</div>
  <div class="input">2</div>
  <div class="input">3</div>
  <div class="input">4</div>
  <div class="input">5</div>
</div>
<div class="infoboxes">
  <div class="infobox">1</div>
  <div class="infobox">2</div>
  <div class="infobox">3</div>
  <div class="infobox">4</div>
  <div class="infobox">5</div>
</div>
```